# Large powers of matrices using eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponentiation

So I am asked to compute the power of a matrix using eigenvalues. Here is the question.

> You are given that the vectors $p_1=(1,1,1), p_2=(2,1,1)$ and $p_3=(1,1,2)$ are eigenvectors to the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 &-4 & 2\\
> 1 &-2 & 2\\ 1 &-5 & 5\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$
> a) Find the corresponding eigen values.
>
> b) Explain why $B=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is an ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> c) Find the coordinate vector $[v]_B$, relative to $B$, if $v=(1,1,0)$.
>
> d) Find $A^{2020}v$.

a) I already found the eigenvalues. They're $1$,$2$ and $3$.

b) It's an ordered basis because the eigenvalues are distict so that means the vectors are linearly independent. The determinant test also confirms this. So they form a valid basis.

c) $[v]_B=<2,0,-1>$.

d) I'm pretty sure I have to diagonalize the matrix here. So that means I get $D=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}$, $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$, and $P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 3 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

This means that $A^{2020}=PD^{2020}P^{-1}$

My problem is that $D^{2020}$ and the subsequent multiplication is so unbelivably large, I am not sure if what I am doing is actually correct.

Is my procedure correct or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: diagnoal matrices are relatively easy to take powers of (that's the point)

Comment: Yes I know that. I just raise each diagonal entry to the power. However, when I do the overall multiplication, the matrix entries are so large, they don't even fit into a calculator. I am not sure if this is till correct or I'm missing something else.

Comment: I don't think the question expects you to write the actual base-10 representation of the entries of the matrix. Just express it in terms of $2^{2020}$ and $3^{2020}$.

Comment: You don’t need to diagonalize the matrix per se. Write $v$ as $ap_1+bp_2+cp_3$ and then use the fact that the $p_k$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you :) .